# sql select rows with exact filters

Tags: sql

| product_id | filter_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 4 | 20 |

Let's say I chose filters with 10 and 5 ids. So there is only one match -> product with product_id = 1. Because only this product maches 10 and 5. How can I take this product with sql?

```
Select product_id from product where filter_id in (5,10)
```

gives me all products which have 5 OR 10. I need to check if they match both filters..

Comment: Which dbms? Postgres, for example, has INTERSECT as a method to accomplish this. Query1 intersect Query2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
Select product_id
from product 
where filter_id in (5, 10)
group by product_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use join:

```sql
SELECT P.product_id
FROM product P
JOIN product P2
  ON P.product_id = P2.product_id
WHERE P.filter_id = 5 AND P2.filter_id = 10
```